# Recommended structure? %70 write %30 read. 10M row. 200 query/sec. Select, update, insert, search

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, full-text-search, architecture

Followings are what I need to do on my project:

1- If a search term is new and unique, then add the search term

2- Show lastest searched 1000 search terms (I don't need to store dates of all search terms)

3- Show 20 similar search terms for a search term

4- If an old search term seaches again, then update view count of the search term.

http://www.ptf.com/tai/tai+ve+dot+kich/ and some other big sites uses first word of search terms for performance I believe. But I am not sure how to apply that structure.

Also, you can get an idea what I'm doing from the link.

This is the current structure and I know it is pretty bad:

```
mysql> use article; SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'searches';
Database changed
+----------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------
-------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name     | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time| Update_time         | Check_time          | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------
-------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| searches | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    | 973577 |             40 |    38960308 | 281474976710655 |     91711488 |         0 |           NULL | 2012-02-08 22:22:33 | 2012-02-09 11:32:31 | 2012-02-08 22:23:50 | utf8_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------
-------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE searches;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| q     | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| date  | datetime     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| view  | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)


mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM searches;
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| searches |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | q           | A         |      973577 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| searches |          1 | date     |            1 | date        | A         |        3416 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| searches |          1 | q        |            1 | q           | NULL      |       21635 |     NULL | NULL   |      | FULLTEXT   |         |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Currently, there are %70 write and %30 read for this table.

Assume there are 10 million rows and 200 searches perform in a second. What is the recommended structure for this kind of need?

I'm struggling with several index and field combinations on this table but I can't make any significant improvement. So I'll be glad if you can help!

Comment: Not really part of the issue, but what is the point of the `id` column if it's not the primary key? I'm assuming that it's an arbitrary number, so let us know if it's not. Also, what version of mysql?

Comment: also, let us know your hardware (amount of RAM, speed of disks, raid setup, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Switch to InnoDB, and

- Set innodb_buffer_pool_size to at least 250M
- Show us the tentative SELECTs
- SHOW CREATE TABLE (DESC is inadequate)

Answer (score -7):

For Such Projects..and scenarios where Write is more than reads, and you need to handle data in large scale, you should go for NoSQL, Like [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org/), [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [Hbase](http://hbase.apache.org) etc.

Comment: Sorry, but generally switching technologies isn't the right answer. This data-set should not be that difficult to achieve required performance.

Comment: Hmm..  I dont Say you cannot do it with RDBMS, But this was a suggestion,I dont Understand Why we have a narrow Minded Approach, For this. See When there is a technology specifically made to handle it, why don't we use it.. Comon, Google, FB, Twitter, All use this, and we know how scalable and Performance oriented it is. 
Please read : http://www.dbta.com/Articles/Columns/Notes-on-NoSQL/Why-NoSQL-69165.aspx

http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-nosql-not-just-google-and

Comment: I don't see how making a suggestion to switch technologies, without any details on how to use that technology for the asker's problem, is helpful at all.

Comment: Sorry for that. I agree to your Point. @DTest

Comment: We do ~ 3000 - 5000 writes per second, ~ 300 - 500 concurrent users, 24/7 on a single PostgreSQL database server. Why would we need NoSQL? What problem would that solve? A dbms is fine piece of technology.